# Asynchronous Web Service & Web Service without response?

Tags: web-services, asynchronous, response

The concept of Asynchronous Web Service is a web service where the client does not have to wait to receive a response from the server. in AJAX this is implemented by having a callback function to process the response. So the server indeed still sends the response to the client.

Is it possible to have an Asynchronous Web Service without response? Is there any platform that provide this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have done asynch web services in the past.  They are very useful.  YOu do not need a detailed response but you at least need an HTTP response, like 200 OK.  If the client that makes the request provides some sort of ID or key for that request, then the client can use the same ID/key to later on query for the result/response of the request.

As far as frameworks that provide this, I do not know of any.  In the past I would just have a shared memory store, like Memcache, to store the state and result of the request.  As long as the state is shared across all nodes, any node can then process the call back request.

EDIT:  Providing a key in the request can be done in either REST or SOAP environment.  HTTP provides multiple places where a key can be communicated.

- GET [query param](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) (REST)
- [HTTP header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) (SOAP/REST)
- Added to the message body of a POST request.  This can be done through two ways.

  - param in the message body (REST)
  - variable or attribute in serialized object (SOAP/REST))

Comment: Hi Jose, thank you for your answer. May I know did you use REST web service or SOAP web service?